# Scraping Angular one-way binding data

Tags: angularjs, angular, python-3.x, web

I want to retrieve data on a web page.

Here is my Python3 code.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://coincheck.com/ja/exchange/charts/coincheck/btc_jpy/300')
print(r.text)
```

And this is a part of the result.

```
<div class="chart">
      <div class="candle-chart" ex-chart-candle chart-height="500" chart-unit="300" arrow-height="20" chart-market="coincheck" chart-pair="btc_jpy" chart-volume>
        <div class="ohlcv">
          <span class="box">
            <span class="key">Date</span>
            <span class="value date-value"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="box">
            <span class="key">O</span>
            <span class="value o-value"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="box">
            <span class="key">H</span>
            <span class="value h-value"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="box">
            <span class="key">L</span>
            <span class="value l-value"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="box">
            <span class="key">C</span>
            <span class="value c-value"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="box">
            <span class="key">V</span>
            <span class="value v-value"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
```

In this HTML, I want to catch "value o-value", "value h-value" etc...
But they look like no value.

Additionally, this web site uses Angular and I think these value are one-way binding.

How do I retrieve these data? Is it impossible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), but with [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup) is much easier.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://coincheck.com/ja/exchange/charts/coincheck/btc_jpy/300')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all("span", class_="value o-value")
```

Comment: So perhaps I didn't get your question...
With my code added to your example I get `[<span class="value o-value"></span>]`. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Yes, it is.
I printed `soup.find_all("span", class_="value o-value")` and this is result: `[<span class="value o-value"></span>]`
It has no value, I think.

Comment: That `span` is empty in fact. Do you want the `O` inside the previous `span`? What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: I think so. No, I don't. On the web page, its value is like 913000, number. But, as you see, when I catch the value via above program, I cannot do it.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, I didn't check the url with a browser before. The 913000 is updated by the javascript code. This is a much more complex matter, I'm afraid... By skimming the source code I believe some angularjs is involved, you can probably have a look at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026930/scraping-an-angularjs-application)